# how to see combox in GridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I want to bind between `List` and `GridView`.
My list includes objects of person, and each person includes list of Jobs.
So I want that the `GridView` to show a `ComboBox` of jobs for each person.

I try to do that:

```
GridViewPersons.DataSource = PersonsList;
```

It populates the `GridView` but ignores from the `Jobs_List` field, and shows only the `String`/`int` in the `GridView`.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried in the GridView itself?

Comment: Can you show the code for the Gridview bind?

Comment: I Just Run this line in the Form_Load Event...
it's automatically populate the gridview with the fields of person. (name, age ,id...) just ignore from the list jobs.

Comment: @user2097810 the `Jobs_List` for each person may be **different**, but when you bind to your grid, the `Jobs_List` column will have the same **datasource** for all the cells in that column. We can change this behavior (I remember that I've done this **once** before) but it's really hacky and maybe buggy. That's also not easy. You should try another approach to display your data.